# ¿Había en español alguna diferencia entre la Ƈ y la C?

Tags: ortografía, pronunciación, historia, letras, alfabeto

Siguiendo con la saga de preguntas basadas en la primera [Orthographía española](http://www.rae.es/recursos/ortografia/primera-ortografia) de 1741, la siguiente trata sobre las posibles diferencias que había entre la C normal y la C con gancho (Ƈ), que existía por aquel entonces:

[image: C con gancho]

Nótese la forma en que se escribía *práƈticas*. Dado que había un símbolo, la *ç*, cuya pronunciación sí difería de la *c*, me preguntaba: ¿la letra *ƈ* tenía alguna diferencia de pronunciación con respecto a la *c*? ¿O era meramente una ligadura que se le ponía a la *c* antes de la *t*?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No estoy del todo seguro de esto pero creo que es una explicación factible.

Aunque no soy diseñador gráfico en mi trabajo hago un poco de diseño y he aprendido algunas cosas. En ciertas tipografías se utilizan ligaduras para enlazar letras con una función puramente estética y los pares de letras que normalmente llevan estas ligaduras son *fi*, *fl*, *ft*, *st* y *ct*, puede que alguna más pero yo diría que esas son las más típicas. Ejemplo:

[image]

Por lo tanto según mi opinión la *Ƈ* no sería mas que una *c* normal y corriente que al preceder a una *t* se enlaza con ella con esa especie de gancho.

Comment: Así es.  Cuando se escribía a mano, esta ligadura permitía al redactor que no tuviese que levantar el bolígrafo (la parte superior de la *c* era el último trazo que haría, y obviamente la parte superior de la *t*, como es hoy, era el primero de esta letra.

Comment: Correcto. No se trata de una ce con gancho, ya que el trazo no es un diacrítico sino una ligadura.